# Datatable Group by Row with Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using DataTables and Jquery for this example. I am also using the extension of DataTables 'RowGroup'.

I have a set of data where one column can have multiple values. I want to group my rows by this column, but if person A has multiple values, I want them to show up under both the row groups.

I have this code sandbox for an example showing the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cartwright-e2sd2

In the example, Garrett Winters has 2 positions, Accountant and Customer Support. I would like him to show up under **both** groupings. Another example is Jenette Caldwell. She is a Development Lead and a Developer. I'd like her to again show up under **both** columns.

Is this possible with Row Grouping from DataTables?

Comment: I think you would need to create separate table rows for each position. Obviously in this case that means having duplicate entries for those people, but if your data was coming from a database then it would not be a problem because you would use separate (database) tables for the person and position.

Comment: I think this is the same conclusion I've come to. Basically, with the data given and the desired outcome, it's not feasible, but if I change the way I'm getting the data, it becomes possible.